# Optimization of Frobenius norm and nuclear norm

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, proximal-operators, nuclear-norm

How to solve the following optimization problem in $ X \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times M} $?

\begin{equation}
    \hat{X} = \arg \min_{X} \frac{1}{2} {\left\| X - Y \right\|}_{F}^{2} + \lambda {\left\| X \right\|}_{\ast}
\end{equation}

Where $ {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{F} $ denotes the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm) and $ {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{\ast} $ denotes the [nuclear norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).  $ Y \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times M} $ and $ \lambda $ are known.

Comment: are you sure that you need to write it $||x-y||^2_F$ instead of  $||x-y||^2_2$. I have seen that people use L2-norm instead of Frobenius norm.

Comment: Are you sure you need it in the Complex Domain?

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with proximal algorithms?  You are asking how to evaluate the prox operator of the nuclear norm.  The answer is given in slide 3-41 in [DTU 2010 - Algorithms for Large Scale Convex Optimization - Proximal Gradient Method](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~elghaoui/Teaching/EE227A/lecture18.pdf).

Comment: I think the nuance is that question deals with Complex Matrices. Does it hold? As the whole course there is for Real Matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem 2.1 in the paper [A Singular Value Thresholding Algorithm for Matrix Completion](http://arxiv.org/abs/0810.3286)

Comment: But, it's still true for complex matrices?