# Minimization of Frobenius Norm and Schur Complement

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, normed-spaces, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

There is a famous problem [Optimization of Frobenius Norm and Nuclear Norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128454/optimization-of-frobenius-norm-and-nuclear-norm); however, this is not I want to ask (about proximal operator).

Suppose I have an easy optimization problem:

$$\min_Q \|Q-Q_N\|_F$$

where $\|\cdot\|_F$  is the Frobenius norm: $\|X\|_F = (\operatorname{tr}(X^TX))^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

We know we can consider the following:

$$\mathcal{A}(Q,t) = \begin{bmatrix}I & Q-Q_N\\ (Q-Q_N)^T & tI \end{bmatrix}\succeq 0$$

By Schur complement we have the following $$tI-(Q-Q_N)^T(Q-Q_N)\succeq 0$$

If $Q\in \mathbb{R}$, the above becomes $$t-\|Q-Q_N\|^2\geq 0 \Rightarrow t\geq \|Q-Q_N\|^2 \geq 0$$ So the original problem is equivalent to 
\begin{align}
&\min_{t,Q} & &t \\
& s.t. & & \|Q-Q_N\|^2 \geq 0
\end{align}   or
\begin{align}
&\min_{t,Q} & &t \\
& s.t. & & \mathcal{A}(t,Q)\succeq 0
\end{align}
The second formulation is a SDP

> My question is: if $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ how to obtain the above convex optimization problem (minimize over $t$) with $\|\cdot\|^2$ replaced by $\|\cdot\|_F^2$

Is there any method **except the vectorization of matrices**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you asking for the problem

$$\text{minimize trace(X) subj. to . } \begin{bmatrix}I & Q-Q_N\\ (Q-Q_N)^T & X \end{bmatrix}\succeq 0$$

which minimizes the Frobenius norm of $Q-Q_N$?

Comment: So now variables in your optimization is "$X$ and $Q$" and obviously, it is a SDP. Right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Can you do something similar for every Schatten p-norm?

Comment: If you mean $(\sum |a_{ij}|_p)^{1/p}$, that's SOCP-representable for rational $p$, but way too complicated for a simple comment. Alternatively, it can be directly represented using the power cone

Comment: I have created a question for this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140803/minimization-of-norm-distance-using-sdps-cone-programming-etc