# Minimization of norm distance using SDPs, cone programming, etc.

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, matrix-norms

Building on top of this question [Minimization of Frobenius norm using SDPs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184430/minimization-of-frobenius-norm-and-schur-complement), I would like to know for what class of norms ($ \Vert \cdot \Vert $ in the following) can we represent the following problem using semidefinite programming (SDP), or cone programming, or some standard optimization problem:

$$
\begin{align*}
& \text{min. } \Vert A - X \Vert  \\
&  \text{s.t. }X \in \mathcal{S}
\end{align*}
$$

where $A$ is a (symmetric) matrix and $\mathcal{S}$ is some convex set, for which the membership condition can be represented say using SDP constraints.

In particular, I am interested in the following cases:

1. The case where the problem can be represented using SDPs.
2. The norm is the [Schatten p-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schatten_norm).
3. The norm is an [Operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm).

Finally, any reference for dealing with this class of problems would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lazy answer would be to simply list the help on norm which lists cases that are supported out of the box in the modelling language [YALMIP](https://yalmip.github.io/command/norm/) (which would write these using LP/SOCP/SDP formulations)

```
 For matrices...
   norm(X)       models the largest singular value of X, max(svd(X)).
   norm(X,2)     is the same as norm(X).
   norm(X,1)     models the 1-norm of X, the largest column sum, max(sum(abs(X))).
   norm(X,inf)   models the infinity norm of X, the largest row sum, max(sum(abs(X'))).
   norm(X,'inf') same as above
   norm(X,'fro') models the Frobenius norm, sqrt(sum(diag(X'*X))).
   norm(X,'nuc') models the Nuclear norm, sum of singular values.
   norm(X,'*')   same as above
   norm(X,'tv')  models the (isotropic) total variation semi-norm 
 For vectors...
   norm(V) = norm(V,2) = standard Euclidean norm.
   norm(V,inf) = max(abs(V)).
   norm(V,1) = sum(abs(V))
```

In addition to that, you have that $(\sum |x_i|^p)^{1/p}$ is conic representable for $p\geq 0$ (second-order cone, or more conveniently but perhaps slightly more esoteric using the power cone) thus covering arbitrary Schatten p-norms on matrices, as long as you can get that operator to act on a vector which upper bounds a sorted vector of the eigenvalues of $X^TX$ (which you also can through intricate modelling...)

Everything is available in (but hidden well...)

> Nesterov, Yurii; Arkadii, Nemirovskii (1995). Interior-Point
>   Polynomial Algorithms in Convex Programming. Society for Industrial
>   and Applied Mathematics. ISBN 0898715156.

Comment: One trivial detail—the vector $p$ norms are SOCP-representable only for rational $p$. You'll need that power code for the fully generic case. And I personally don't know about the representability of induced matrix $p$-norms (other than $1$, $2$, and $\infty$).

Comment: @Johan I don't understand what you mean by: 'In addition to that, you have that... (which you also can through intricate modelling...)'. Could you elaborate/ give a simple example?

Comment: What I mean is that you through SDP modelling can represent  the function $f(v)$ where $v$ are the eigenvalues of a symmetrix matrix and $f$ is any permutation invariant conic representable function.